# Session in Rails vs Session in rhodes

Tags: rhomobile, rhodes

In Rails its easy to store and retrieve session variables.

for e.g

```
session[:user_id] = @current_user.id
```

I was wondering if there is something this like in rhodes too.

Like in rails request parameters are accessible through

```
params['name']
```

while in rhodes its

```
@params['name']
```

If there is nothing like session variable, can anyone suggest some work around for managing sessions. like using global variables that are available across multiple requests.

Comments/Hints, please?

thanx.

Answer (score 2):

I implemented my own session in rhodes.
Assuming that a rhodes app will have only one user you don't need to detect in wich user or "session" you are, so you will have only one session.
I created a global hash, named `$session`, where you put and get your values:

In the application.rb I put this:

```
$session ||= {}
```

And I use it thus:

```
$session[:user] = 'john'

puts $session[:user]
```

Comment: yes, that can be a work around. For now I am using some static variable inside a class(say UserInfo) in application.rb. I am setting that variable after login and putting nil on logout. I thought using global variable/s wont be a good design. can u comment on this. and thnx for your answer :)

Comment: OK, using global variables is disencouraged, but I did this in the start of development and when I was learning ruby, so I did not know the right patterns. In my opinion your approach is correct and better than the mine

Comment: Your answer is one of the possible solutions, so i would vote it. though i would wait for some one to answer or comment a better solution.

Comment: At this stage, I too am learning ruby, rails(so i am waiting for still better solution). Since you must have worked a little more on rho-mobile, can u recommend some references to get on with rhomobile/rhodes? I am kind of newbie to this mobile stuff. i have some knowledge of rails. I can see many references/screen casts for rails but not much for rho mobile/rhodes. thnx in advance.

Comment: OK, Thank you by the upvote. The unique references I have found were the rhomobile docs page and the forum. Althoug, I have learned a lot by studying the rhomobile source code, inside the rhodes' gem or directly in GitHub (github.com/rhomobile/rhodes).

Comment: I know I'm kinda late but I found this: http://docs.rhomobile.com/rhodes/application#appapplication-class

Answer (score 0):

You could also store persistent values in the Redis database as a key/value pairs database.

Comment: thnx. can you also provide some references/example for the same? it would be great..

Comment: can we use redis database on client side(on mobile phone) also? because i guess it runs on server side

Comment: You're getting a bit beyond my meagre RhoMobile skills here.  If you do not allow that class/object to sync with the remote server the data/value pairs will remain unique to that phone.  So you could use it as a persistent storehouse for that phone/user.